# EditText дублирует введённый текст при использовании InputFilter

Tags: android, android-edittext

При вводе или удалении символа текст дублируется, но не каждый раз, а через раз.
Под дебаггером вижу, что перед дублированием `dstart=dend=dest.length`, `source` содержит весь текст, который должен быть после изменения, `start=0`, `end=source.length`
Код фильтра:

```
class FileNameInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char ch = source.charAt(i);
            if ("/\\:*?\"<>|".indexOf(ch) == -1) {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Как это побороть?

**Дополнение**
Дублируется в пределах слова, строго через раз, вот так выглядит ввод "Hello World!":

> `HHelHHelloHHelHHello WWorWWorldWWorWWorld!`

Цифры вводятся и удаляются нормально, глючат только буквы.

Comment: может вместо sb.append(ch) написать sb.setText()?

Comment: @retr12 нет такого метода у `StringBuilder`

Comment: у вас этот фильтр случаем не добавляется дважды?

Comment: @Style-7, нет - однажды `editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new FileNameInputFilter()});`

Comment: Я бы добавил проверку `sb` сразу после цикла. `if (sb.length()==0) return null;`. Еще вот эту [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179158/) попалась на глаза.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, это не то - если проверять, то на совпадение длины и содержимого с источником, у вас получается если в источнике только запрещённые символы - оставить их, а нужно наоборот удалить: `return "";`. Мой вариант работает почти как надо, только после ввода знаков пунктуации добавляются пробелы - это всё приколы авто-дополнения, я так понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашёл: нужно **обязательно** возвращать `null` если фильтр ничего не изменил. Но непонятно почему возврат эквивалентного текста ломает логику. Баг фреймворка?
Этом вариант работает почти как надо, за исключением того, что после ввода знаков пунктуации добавляются пробелы - они идут отдельным вызовом и поэтому я не знаю как их отфильтровать, не затрагивая введённые юзером намеренно.

```
class FileNameInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean changed = false;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char ch = source.charAt(i);
            if ("/\\:*?\"<>|".indexOf(ch) == -1) {
                sb.append(ch);
            } else {
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        if (!changed) {
            return null;
        }
        return sb;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Логика работы фильтра: если что-то не нравится - возвратить пустую строку, иначе null (оставить без изменения). Фактически проверка происходит посимвольно за исключением вставки из буфера.

```
    EditText edit = new EditText( this );
    setContentView( edit );
    edit.setFilters( new InputFilter[]{
            new InputFilter(){
                @Override
                public CharSequence filter( CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned spanned, int i2, int i3 ){
                    final String invalidChars = "/\\:*?\"<>|";
                    for( int i = start; i < end; i++ ){
                        if( invalidChars.indexOf( source.charAt( i ) ) != -1 ){
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
    } );
```

Comment: Вариант. Но копипаст и авто-дополнение будут работать неадекватно, если содержат "запрещённые" символы.

Comment: @woesss в автоподбоборе запрещенные символы ни разу не встречал :), там же строго текст

Comment: Я не говорил что буду фильтровать только спец символы - это просто пример одного из фильтров.